# Datetime picker - jquery mobile

Tags: jquery

I found a jquery mobile [data time picker](http://mobipick.sustainablepace.net/demo.html) on the web.

I followed all the instructions. In page, all css and js are installed successfully. In order to use date time picker in textboxes i use below code:

Script:
    $(document).on("pagecreate", "#demo", function() 
    {
        var picker = $("input[type='text']", this);
        picker.mobipick();
        picker.on("change", function() 
        {
            var date = $(this).val();
            // formatted date
            var dateObject = $(this).mobipick("option", "date");
        });
    });

HTML:

```
<div id="demo" class="content no-heading" >
    <h1><span>Financial Transactions</span></h1>
    <div  data-role="content" style="padding:5px 0 6px 6px;"  id="SearchTermsText">
        <label for="BeginDateText">Begin date</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="beginDate" style="width:95%;" value=""></input> 
        <br />
        <label for="EndDateText">End date:</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="endDate" style="width:95%;" value=""></input>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="SubmitAction('Search');"></input>
    </div> 
</div>
```

but when I click textboxes, nothing happens. There's no date time picker, why?

Comment: `</input>` <-- these are not valid. A simple validation test would've shown you this.

Comment: netbeans gives error if i dont put them.

Comment: When the  `pagecreate` event occurs, has the DOM loaded at that point? If not, it could just be the issue that you're trying to select the input elements that have not finished loading yet.